# Horizontal divs not in line

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have rows of divs created in Jquery , [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwl707/JUbAY/2/)

the generated html is

```
<div id="thisPage">
  <div id="vehicles" class="wrapper">
    <div class="divd spacer">&nbsp;</div> 
    <div id="Paul " title="Driver Details" class="divd i100">i1001<br>Paul </div>
    <div id="Simon " title="Driver Details" class="divd i100">i1002<br>Simon </div>
    <div id="Phil " title="Driver Details" class="divd i100">i1003<br>Phil </div>
    <div id="Lee " title="Driver Details" class="divd i100">i1004<br>Lee </div>
    <div id="Martin" title="Driver Details" class="divd i100">i1005<br>Martin </div>
    <div id="" title="Driver Details" class="divd i100">i1006<br></div>
    <div id="Tom Robson" title="Driver Details" class="divd i60">i601<br>Tom Robson</div>
    <div id="Alan Linney " title="Driver Details" class="divd i60">i602<br>Alan Linney </div>
  </div>

  <div id="vehicles" class="wrapper" style="top:60px">
    <div id="2013-03-11" class="divd dateWeekday">Monday 11<br>March</div>
    <div id="Paul " title="Driver Details" class="divd i100"> JOB D </div>
    <div id="Simon " title="Driver Details" class="divd i100"> JOB D </div>
    <div id="Phil " title="Driver Details" class="divd i100"> JOB D </div>
    <div id="Lee " title="Driver Details" class="divd i100"> JOB D </div>
    <div id="Martin " title="Driver Details" class="divd i100"> JOB D </div>
    <div id="" title="Driver Details" class="divd i100"> JOB D </div>
    <div id="Tom " title="Driver Details" class="divd i60"> JOB D </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the styling is

```
.wrapper {
    position:absolute; vertical-align:middle ; 
}
.divd { 
    display: inline-block;
    margin:2px 2px 2px 2px ;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;   
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:#999; 
    border-radius:5px;  
    z-index:200;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:bottom ;
}
.dateWeekday {
        width: 120px;
        background-color:#9CF ;
        margin:2px 2px 2px 2px ;
    }
.spacer {
        width: 120px;
        margin:2px 2px 2px 2px ;
    }
```

All works fine but the result in a browser shows the second row offset to the first as shown by the red line in the picture below, How can I correct this ? any help please ?

[Screen grab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70s6Y.png)

Comment: what browser are you using? I am using Chrome and JSFiddle works fine

Comment: Which browser? All of them?

Comment: Element IDs cannot start with a number: 2013-03-11

Comment: Im using Chrome, and yes JSFiddle works fine, but the same code when run from script shows this offset result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
.wrapper {
    position:absolute; vertical-align:middle ; 
}
.divd { 
background-color: #999999;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 1px 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 200;
}
.dateWeekday {
        width: 120px;
        background-color:#9CF ;
    }
.spacer {
        width: 120px;
    }
```

so now you have on every divd a margin to the right of 1px;

```
margin-right:1px; /* is the same as margin:0 1px 0 0; */
```

the margin work like this:

```
margin:topPX rightPX bottomtPX leftPX; /* if four */
```

or:

```
    margin:top&bottomPX right&leftPX; /*if only two */
```

margin:2px 2px 2px 2px ; is the same as:

```
 margin:2px; /* if just one its the same top+right+bottom+left */
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.wrapper div {
   float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with rows of divs, you should have a wrapper for each row of divs, it helps a lot if you ever need to change design

Comment: I have a wrapper for each row ? <div id="vehicles" class="wrapper">

Comment: Both wrappers have same id, you need an unique wrapper for each row. I guess that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper
 {
vertical-align:middle ;
float:left; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i know, this is NOT an answer, i needed to post picture.

Here is what i see from this PC.

[image]

Perhaps you could **give more information** about your situation, like, the **specific browser targeted**, the **full html** code ( to see doctype, BOM mark, character-encoding, etc etc )